# In blender can we use svg as material texture?

Tags: texturing

I am aware of importing SVG as path. 
What i want t do is to use SVG as texture like any other image on material.

I also read about  [vectex](https://code.google.com/p/vectex/)

[vectex demo vudeo](https://youtu.be/jXFp3wPLUPs)

not sure how it is supposed to be used

Comment: there is a manual page: https://code.google.com/p/vectex/wiki/Documentation

Comment: @ Cegaton i have gone through the urls you shared and thats not my question. I want to use it as png file in texture stack of material

Comment: Is there a way to use Vectex with Blender 3.2 ?